# Node.js: Track new files in a directory

Tags: node.js, fs

I would like to track new files in a directory. I used the script given in the documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('mydir/', function (event, filename) {
    console.log('event is: ' + event);
    if (filename) {
        console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
    } else {
        console.log('filename not provided');
    }
});
```

And I added files to `mydir/` using `touch hello.txt` for example.

When running the script, I don't get the new file name, because the emitted event is `rename`!! Here is the console output.

```
event is: rename
filename not provided
```

How can I get the file new name `hello.txt`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same page also describes your issue:

> Providing filename argument in the callback is not supported on every
>   platform (currently it's only supported on Linux and Windows). Even on
>   supported platforms filename is not always guaranteed to be provided.

I think your best bet is to switch to another module providing similar functionality, like [watch](https://github.com/mikeal/watch) (which I don't have any experience with myself).

Comment: Thanks robertklep. I'm currently using a Mac, that's why I have the issue with fs. I'll switch to watch.

Answer (score 2):

```js
fs.watch('somedir', (event, filename) => {
})
```

The `filename` here works, all you need is to track the second parameter.

Mac 10.11.3, Node v5.9

Answer (score 1):

**chokidar** at https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar was easy to setup. Follow the instructions in the README to setup. Here's a quick example I used to detect when a video file was generated in a /video subfolder relative to the root of my Node.js app:

- Install Node.js (includes NPM)
- Generate package.json `npm init`
- Install Chokidar library into /node_modules subfolder and save the dependency to package.json `npm install chokidar --save`
- Create an example program file (i.e. touch `video.js`)
- Create a folder to watch (i.e. `mkdir videos`)
- Add the following code to video.js (as described in the README, which will watch for changes in the /videos subfolder and ignore filenames prefixed with a full stop):

  `var chokidar = require('chokidar');
  chokidar.watch('./videos', {ignored: /[\/\\]\./}).on('all', function(event, path) { console.log(event, path); });`
- Start the program `node video.js` that prints to output indicating that the /videos subdirectory and its contents are being watched, i.e.

  `$ node video.js
  addDir ./videos`
- Copying/Saving a file (i.e. test.mov) into the /videos subdirectory prints the following to standard output in terminal:

  `add videos/test.mov`
- Removing the file prints the following to terminal:

  `unlink videos/test.mov`